# Let $B$ be countable subset of $\mathbb R^n$ where $n > 1$. Prove $\mathbb R^n\setminus B$ is connected space

Tags: general-topology

Let $B$ be countable subset of $\mathbb R^n$ where $n > 1$. Prove $\mathbb R^n\setminus B$ is connected space. But I have to show this without arc-connectedness. Hint is to use the fact that sum of connected spaces which have common point is again connected.

To be honest, I don't know how to use the hint. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that $[0,1]^n\setminus\{p\}$ is connected, where $p$ is arbitrary. This is not difficult, let me know if you need help. Now you can cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ by small enough cubes and use the hint.

to see the connectedness: use induction. I'll leave the proof for $n=2$ to you. wlog assume that $p=(1/2,\dots,1/2)$. Then write $X=[0,1]^n\setminus\{p\}$, and let
$$X_1=[0,1]^{n-1}\times[0,1/2]\setminus \{p\}, X_2=[0,1]^{n-1}\times [1/2,1]\setminus\{p\}$$
Then $X$ is a sum of $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $X_1\cong X_2$, so we need only prove that $X_1$ is connected. But we can consider e.g. 
$$L=\{0\}^{n-1}\times[0,1/2]\cong [0,1/2]$$
Then consider
$$X_t=[0,1]^{n-1}\times \{t\}$$
if $t<1/2$ and
$$X_{1/2}=([0,1]\setminus\{1/2\})^{n-1}\times\{1/2\}\cong ([0,1]\setminus\{1/2\})^{n-1}$$
using induction this is connected. $X_1=\cup_{t\in[0,1/2]}X_t$ and each of the $X_t$ is connected, and intersects $L$, which is also connected. A standard theorem shows that $X_1$ is connected.

Comment: I don't know which equivalent definition of connectedness I suppose to use. Is it fine to try showing that there is continuous function between $[0,1]^N$ and $[0,1]^N \setminus \{p\}$

Comment: You can use the hint again, see my edit